# Adding Ozone to my sky simulation

Tags: c++, atmosphere

I implemented a simulation for the colour of the sky a while ago by following the scratch a pixel tutorial: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/procedural-generation-virtual-worlds/simulating-sky

I adapted it for the actual sun position and am able to get realistic sky colours during the day. However, I noticed that after sunset/ before sunrise, the colours are greyish when they should be deep blue. After researching about this, I read that this is due to the ozone absorption not being present in my model.

I used extinction coefficients : (3.426,8.298,0.356) * 0.06e-5 -> found on https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/eacom/frostbite/files/s2016-pbs-frostbite-sky-clouds-new.pdf

and also read that since the ozone does not scatter, it should only be added to the transmittance value.
[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9KUP.jpg)

Therefore, I modified the code from scratchapixel as follows:

```
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        vec3 samplePosition = ray_in2.origin() + (tCurrent + 
        segmentLength * 0.5f) * ray_in2.direction();
        float height = samplePosition.length() - atmosphere.earthRadius;

        // compute optical depth for light
        float hr = exp(-height / atmosphere.Hr) * segmentLength;
        float hm = exp(-height / atmosphere.Hm) * segmentLength;
        float ho = exp(-height / atmosphere.Hr)* segmentLength*(6e-7);
        opticalDepthR += hr;
        opticalDepthM += hm;
        opticalDepthO += ho;

        // light optical depth
        float t0Light, t1Light;

            ...
        for (j = 0; j < numSamplesLight; ++j) {
            vec3 samplePositionLight = samplePosition + (tCurrentLight + 
            segmentLengthLight * 0.5f) * sunDir;
            float heightLight = samplePositionLight.length() - 
            atmosphere.earthRadius;

            if (heightLight < 0) break;
            opticalDepthLightR += exp(-heightLight / atmosphere.Hr) * 
            segmentLengthLight;
            opticalDepthLightM += exp(-heightLight / atmosphere.Hm) * 
            segmentLengthLight;
            opticalDepthLightO += exp(-heightLight / atmosphere.Hr) * 
            segmentLengthLight*(6e-7); ;
            tCurrentLight += segmentLengthLight;
        }
        if (j == numSamplesLight) {
            vec3 tau = (betaR) * (opticalDepthR + opticalDepthLightR) + 
           betaM * 1.1f * (opticalDepthM + opticalDepthLightM)+ betaO*
          (opticalDepthO + opticalDepthLightO);
            vec3 attenuation(exp(-tau.x()), exp(-tau.y()), exp(-
            tau.z()));
```

Summary:

- I added variable opticalDepthO and opticalDepthLightO which
  are calculated same as the optical depth for Rayleigh, but multiplied
  by 6e-7.
- Then, the sum of opticalDepthLightO and opticalDepthO is multiplied by the extiction coefficient for ozone and added to variable tau.

Problem is, I see no difference in my sky colour before and after
adding ozone. Can someone guide me to what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 6e-7 is small... how does it compare to the magnitude of tCurrentLight?

Comment: @UKMonkey according to the image attached in my question, the ozone density function is 6e-7 times larger than rayleigh one, which is why I multiplied by that number

Comment: if you're adding 6e-7 to 1 ... then I wouldn't expect to see any difference either.  If I'm adding it to 6e-5 I'd question if I'd see it.  If I'm adding it to 6e-9 then I'd expect to be blinded by it.  Hence my question - how do your numbers, when you put in a breakpoint, compare?

Comment: @UKMonkey In fact it doesn't make much of a difference except during sunset/sunrise, which is why most people dont implement the ozone

Comment: Then you seem to have answered your own question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, during sunset/sunrise there should be a difference but there isnt. As can be read here:http://skyrenderer.blogspot.com.mt/2012/10/ozone-absorption.html

Comment: Can you show us the problem with images?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit https://ibb.co/j2tQhn, without ozone absorption sky looks grey. After adding absorption it should look deep blue. However, I saw no difference so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: No, I mean, show us _the problem_ with images. I already saw those examples on the linked site.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand of what images you are requesting. My current image is grey like the one I just sent.